# Sendgird transactional email and template with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

This is a Rails 5 app, and I am using the smtpapi gem. In my controller I am calling:

```
NewsletterSignupMailer.send_signup_email(email_address).deliver_now
```

and in app/mailers/newsletter_signup_mailer I have...

```
class NewsletterSignupMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: 'mark@remotegig.io'
    def send_signup_email(email_address)
        @email = email_address
        headers "X-SMTPAPI" => {
                                                     to: @email,
                                                      filters: {
                                                        templates: {
                                                          settings: {
                                                            enable: 1,
                                                            template_id: "7d783012-5044-4a9b-9875-6f3453r3c20"
                                                          }
                                                        }
                                                      }
                                                    }.to_json
    end
end
```

In config/environment.rb I have `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` configured with my sendgrid username and password. When I call the mailer I don't get any emails, but no errors in the rails console, only:

`NewsletterSignupMailer#send_signup_email: processed outbound mail in 0.2ms`

...so not sure how to trouble shoot this, or event see what the response from sendgrid is.

Comment: Are you running this locally? If so, you'll need to do additional configurations to actually get the email to send from your local server. If you're seeing the mail was processed, once you push to heroku/aws/whatev the mail will actually send.

Comment: Yes, this is local/dev. I added the `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` to config/env/development.rb and still not seeing emails come through.